# Dell 7470 Application Crashes

Tags: windows-10, bsod, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude E7470 laptop, purchased late 2016. Currently standard apart from an Intel 600p 1tb SSD.

I am experiencing frequent application crashes - Excel, Word, Visual Studio 2015, SQL Management Studio. The Video driver also crashes regularly. It occasionally crashes as I am trying to shut it down (BSOD - but with a red tinge!).

It is running Windows 10 with the creator update, but was crashing before the update.

Its a reasonably high spec machine. I've attempted to increase the memory, but put it back to the original spec as I was trying to eliminate that as a cause. (i.e., I have tried different memory in the laptop, but is still has application crashes)

I am pretty sure that it is not the motherboard as this was replaced due to a battery charging error.

The SSD SMART information says that it is 100% good

I have done a complete reinstall blanking the disk, so I do not think that it is the installation.

Has anyone got any ideas of what the cause might be?

Some Example Logs from event viewer (as requested by Will.Beninger)

```
Faulting application name: git-remote-https.exe, version: 2.12.1.1, time stamp: 0x00000000
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0xb79b6ddb
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000002e0a7
Faulting process ID: 0x5570
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2d7783426ec01
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-remote-https.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: 3a0715e3-8257-40ea-8d12-6a96b10fcb12
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

and

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d85
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.2098.0, time stamp: 0x59028d36
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00023bca
Faulting process ID: 0x24fc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2d79814a1c918
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report ID: fd052dc6-7c8c-49f8-8973-7ffdef804048
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

and

```
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.8067.2115, time stamp: 0x5918b6d6
Faulting module name: mso98win32client.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5918d2d8
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000bbc34
Faulting process ID: 0x1588
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2d79f0e072a91
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso98win32client.dll
Report ID: 2e1c6592-13f4-42ea-bef0-4ff6ab0be041
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

and

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.8067.2115, time stamp: 0x5918bd78
Faulting module name: mso98win32client.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5918d2d8
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000b9968
Faulting process ID: 0x1130
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2d7a01c00f785
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso98win32client.dll
Report ID: 01303d51-d498-4ca8-9427-3e1acf15eefd
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

and (where I get the BSOD with a red tinge)

```
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x000000ca (0x0000000000000005, 0xffffaf8b67dec660, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000). A dump was saved in: C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
```

Comment: Would recommend you look further into the problem through the **Event Viewer** into what the error message that it is providing and then bring that back into the question. To answer the question people will need more information. As well, please clarify if you have modified the **paging** values for your OS. When running out of memory, your laptop should just be writing to disk. If you've disabled this, that may be causing your BSOD crashes.

Comment: I've not changed any of the paging settings - it's a fairly standard windows installation.

Comment: Well your BSOD is throwing out a [Plug&Play error](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xca--pnp-detected-fatal-error). Make sure your drivers are up to date and if possible use the CD that came with your Laptop/Motherboard. 

Your errors in all of your application point to 0xc0000005 which is an Access Violation Error. Can be bad RAM, bad driver, etc. Bit of a hard one to nail down. [Can try some of the options here.](http://compfreakstars.blogspot.com/2011/11/0xc0000005-error-every-day-many.html). See my answer for my recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your most recent update with event logs. I would recommend some of the following troubleshooting steps (in order of time, cost, complexity).

**1)** Run System File Checker tool from admin Command Window:

> sfc /scannow

**2)** Update all of your drivers for attached devices. Your Plug & Play is hitting a BSOD due to a [0xCA: PNP_DETECTED_FATAL_ERROR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xca--pnp-detected-fatal-error) with a parameter of 0x5. This is defined as (copied over):

> PDO freed while linked in devnode tree: The object manager reference count on a PDO dropped to zero while the devnode was still linked in the tree. (This usually indicates that the driver is not adding a reference when returning the PDO in a query IRP.)

**a)** Open up device manager (right click my computer, manage) and right click on your plugged in devices and select update driver
  **b)** Find official drivers from online where possible.

**3)** Change out the RAM. Not ideal, but it's worth a try to see if this is a hardware issue.

Comment: Thanks again for your attention. I have run sfc / scannow and it picked up some errors - took several passes, but it runs with no errors now.

Comment: I've updated all drivers. I had been keeping the drivers up to date using the dell website, but there were a couple that updated - "NFC Proximity Provider" and "Dell Control Vault..."

Comment: I've seen a lot of improvement. I still have some crashes but it's on sleeping rather than working within applications. I did change the memory, but this has not made a difference. One thing that was not on your list was a firmware update from Intel for the SSD. If you were to add this to your answer it might help other.